# Is there a way to connecto Spark-Sql with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, apache-spark, sqlalchemy, pyspark

Is there a way to connect Spark-Sql with sqlalchemy 
I have legacy code that uses sqlalchemy
How could i make it use spark-sql ,can i make sqlalchemy as the translation layer to spark-sql ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes ,
look at this project 
https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive

There are some adjustments you will need to do ,
fortunately SQLAlchemy is build for that

Answer (score 1):

While PyHive is a popular option, consider exploring [`SparkORM`](https://medium.com/@andrei.suiu/making-pyspark-schema-management-more-pythonic-with-sparkorm-8839cd13e147). This library, available on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/sparkorm/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/asuiu/sparkorm), simplifies schema maintenance and table creation in Spark-SQL, offering easy extensibility. It's worth checking out for a straightforward integration with your existing SQLAlchemy-based code.

Answer (score -5):

Short answer: No! This would be the same thing as if we could use PostgresSQL with Spark-SQL. Spark-SQL has its own SQL dialect and follows [more Hive style](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive). You should convert your sqlalchemy code to conform with Spark-SQL.

Comment: Thanks, mate  , according to this
https://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HortonworksSparkODBCDriverUserGuide.pdf
it seems that we can connect to spark using odbc , if this is the case we should probably be able to use  sqlalchemy

Comment: This document is from 2015... And yeh you could but this doesn't seem to be open source...